# Basic 2SLS IV Questions in Stata

Tags: stata, econometrics, instrumental-variables, 2sls

**(1)** If I believe my instrument is exogenous conditional upon a few exogenous variables, do I include them only in the first stage? I.e. would the command be:

```
ivregress 2sls Y (X= inst1 inst 2 exog1 exog2) exog3 exog4
```

Where `Y` is the dependent variable, `X` is an endogenous variable, `inst1` and `2` are the instruments for `X`, `exog1` and `exog2` are what make the instrument exogenous to the error in the second stage, and `exog3` and `exog4` are just second stage variables that enhance precision? Would I need to include `exog1` and `exog2` outside the parenthesis also?

**(2)** If I want to interact endogenous variable `X` with `exog3`, how should I instrument `X` and interact it? As follows? `ivregress 2sls Y (X*exog3= inst1 inst 2 exog1 exog2) exog4`

Answer (score 5):

You need to include all your exogenous variables in both the first and the second stage as otherwise you might end up with biased estimates. For a discussion of why having some exogenous variables in the first but not in the second stage is problematic see [here](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/statistics/instrumental-variables-regression/). Given your setup the correct syntax for Stata would be
`ivregress 2sls Y exog1 exog2 exog3 exog4 (X = inst1 inst2)`

As a side note: instead of `ivregress` you might want to use `ivreg2` which is a user written command that provides many more diagnostic statistics for your 2SLS model.

For the interaction of the endogenous variable and `exog3` you would also need to generate an interaction between the instruments and `exog3`. In a model like
$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta_1 \text{exog1}_i + \beta_2 \text{exog2}_i + \beta_3 \text{exog3}_i + \beta_4 \text{exog4}_i + \gamma X_i + \epsilon_i$$
you said that you can instrument $X$ by running the first stage
$$X_i = a + \rho_1 \text{exog1}_i + \rho_2 \text{exog2}_i + \rho_3 \text{exog3}_i + \rho_4 \text{exog4}_i + \phi_1 \text{inst1}_i + \phi_2 \text{inst2}_i + e_i $$
and then use the fitted values of this in the second stage. In the same spirit, if `inst1` and `inst2` are valid instruments for `X`, then `inst1*exog3` and `inst2*exog3` will be valid instruments for `X*exog3`, i.e. for a model
$$Y_i = \alpha + \beta_1 \text{exog1}_i + \beta_2 \text{exog2}_i + \beta_3 \text{exog3}_i + \beta_4 \text{exog4}_i + \gamma \text{(X$_i$ $\cdot$ exog3$_i$)} + \eta_i$$
the first stage would be
$
\begin{align}
\text{(X$_i$ $\cdot$ exog3$_i$)} &= c + \delta_1 \text{exog1}_i + \delta_2 \text{exog2}_i + \delta_3 \text{exog3}_i + \delta_4 \text{exog4}_i + \psi_1 \text{(inst1 $\cdot$ exog3)}_i  \newline &+ \psi_2 \text{(inst2 $\cdot$ exog3)}_i + u_i
\end{align}
$

In Stata the least complicated way would be to generate the interactions by hand

```
gen Xexog3 = X*exog3
gen inst1exog3 = inst1*exog3
gen inst2exog3 = inst2*exog3
ivregress 2sls Y exog1 exog2 exog3 exog4 (X Xexog3 = inst1 inst2 inst1exog3 inst2exog3)
```

This type of question has been asked before on the Statalist, so if you are interested in further discussion of the problem have a look [here](http://www.stata.com/statalist/archive/2012-05/msg01165.html).