# Can I have an interaction-term between the predicted endogenous variable and other exogenous variables in the second stage Modell of a 2SLS?

Tags: r, instrumental-variables, 2sls

I have a question regarding 2SLS and interaction-terms between the predicted endogenous variable and a set of exogenous variables (second stage).

I want to calculate the effect of an endogenous variable (X) on the dependent variable (Y) in interaction with a set of exogenous variables (X2 + X3 + X4). Normally, without an interaction, I would use an exogenous instrumental variable (Z) that explains a portion of the variance in X and isolate this variance using a two-stage least squares model (2SLS). Can I still do this, if I want to include an interaction term in the second stage model? **AND: How would the code look like in R-studio?** Because I am not sure if I have to include the interaction also on the left side of the calculation. Or only in the second level. Thanks for any help!

My code (R-Studio) for the 2SLS-Model would be like this:

````
first_stage <- plm(X ~ Z * (X1 + X2 + X3), data = data, model = "within", effect = "individual")

X_hat <- predict(first_stage, type = "response")

data <- cbind.data.frame(data, X_hat)
data <- pdata.frame(data, index = c("country", "year"))```

second_stage <- plm(Y ~ X_hat * (X1 + X2 + X3), data = data, model = "within", effect = "individual")
````

Comment: See [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/180397/2sls-with-endogenous-interaction-term) answer.

Comment: I would be glad, if you could help me out, as I don't fully understand the answer to the other question you provided...

Comment: Which part is unclear?